# How to get bar click event from horizontalbar charts of MPcharts in android?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

I have used Horizontal bar charts in my dashboard.

I want to navigate to another activity by clicking particular bar of that chart.

How can i do this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's actually pretty easy, all you have to do is use the `OnChartValueSelectedListener` and start your new `Activity` from the callback methods.

You can find an example of how that works [**here**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).

Basically, implement the listener in your class that holds the chart:

```
public class SomeClass implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {
```

Set the listener to the chart:

```
chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
```

Start your new activity in the callback:

```
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
    // start new activity
}
```

Comment: Also, just in case one only wants to trigger clicks and not finger swipes or drags you will need to make sure to disable this chart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(false);

Comment: @philip what if I don't want the bars to be selected/touched but chart to be zoomed

Comment: got it..        `mChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);` Amazing library Philipp